# Were there significant changes in C++ templates standard since 2002?

Tags: c++, templates

For the coming holiday season on the beach I would like to buy this book [C++ Templates: The Complete Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201734842).

I am **NOT** asking if this book can be recommended, because then this question will be immediately closed as *too broad* or *primarily opinion-based*.

**My question:**

Were there - if any - significant changes in the C++ template standard since 2002 which would mean the book may be *expired* [because these changes cannot be handled in this book] or didn't really change that much and therefore the book is still up-to-date.

Comment: Significant changes?  Several whole new versions of the language ([C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11), [C++14](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B14)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2002 is ancient history, predating both C++03 and *especially* C++11 and C++14. *Many* things have changed - also in relation to templates.

Just a few examples:

Alias template : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias

Extern template : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Extern_template

Variadic templates : http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#variadic-templates

decltype : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype

declval : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval

And much, much more..